# How to prevent script from slowing down the longer it runs?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, memory-leaks, tumblr

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfhmu0gc/)

I've made a script that takes a small chat box ( *I'm using it for Tumblr.com's instant messaging system* ) and parses the text into something I can easily copy + paste into an external text file in an attempt to create some sort of chat log of very old conversations.

The way Tumblr loads its old messages is that every time you scroll up on the box, it loads 10 more messages and adds them to the DOM. I've constructed my script so that a `MutationObserver` will check when the new messages are loaded and then my script will take the messages, strip them of all editing and paste them into a programmatically created div that I can then highlight everything on and paste it into an external file for safekeeping.

My script works perfectly fine with one catch — if I keep it running for more than 1.5 hrs or so, the script begins to slow down to almost 4x slower than it originally was running at. Now I've been doing some reading about memory leaks, but can't find anything in my script that would make it "leak".

Nevertheless, in my Activity Monitor on OSX the `Google Chrome Helper` task that is running for my browser tab that I'm running the script on continues to tick up in Memory usage, like so—

[image: memory usage of tab]

(*the script was at **1.06GB** only 30 min ago*). I'm not sure if this means there is a memory leak or not, but as my script continues to slow down, I can only assume this is the case unless something else is going on!

When I first ran my script I thought maybe my script was slowing down because I was adding such a large amount of `<p></p>` tags to the DOM and never clearing them, so I added a button that will stop the loop so that I can copy the text and save it in an external text file, and then clear all the `<p></p>` tags from the DOM, and then resume parsing. This does seem to have sped up the script somewhat, but not enough to explain why it's slowing down so much over time.

Is there something fundamentally wrong about my script that I'm missing? Or something about how memory works for Google Chrome in general? I'm very confused, so any documentation or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some source code?

Comment: I have the Fiddle linked at the very top!